# TFS - Query items without link

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

**TL;DR;**
How can I search for `Bug`s that do not have a `Active` `Issue` as `Child` or `Related`?

**Long Version**
As we solve bugs, sometimes we find problems that must be escalated to someone else because it deals with business rules or non-tech questions. In order to do that, we create a Issue, as a "child" of the bug... if any other bug is affected by the same problem, he is linked as well, but the link is "related"...
Right now I have quite a few bugs, and I would like to create a custom query for bugs that are not blocked, meaning, bugs that do not have a active issue related or child... closed issues are OK, but active are not...
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I might not have understood you correctly but I think this should do the job.
We have a direct link query for top level items matching Work Item Type = Bug, and you can add further restrictions if you want.

Then we have a linked Work Item filter for items of Type = Issue.  And optionally restrict this to only Child or Related links and also State = Active.

Then the key is the Filter Option: Only return items that do not have matching links

[image: Direct Link Query]

So we should only see active bugs which do not have any linked Issues.

Comment: now i'm only getting items that HAVE active issues... bugs without issues are gone...

Comment: Can you post your query or a screenshot?